# Is there a generally valid assessment for $\vert a+b\vert^r $($a$,$b$ real, $r$ positive)?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have: $\vert a+b\vert^2$ then we obviously have 
$$\vert a+b\vert^2 \leq \vert 2a\vert^2+\vert 2b\vert^2=2a^2+2b^2$$

However, how does this look like for a general exponent $r$?

The reason for it is that I know that $\mathbb{E}\vert x_1\vert^{4+\epsilon}$ and $\mathbb{E}\vert x_2\vert^{4+\epsilon}$ exists, so is finite and I want to show that $\mathbb{E}\vert x_1^2+x_2^2\vert^{2+\epsilon/2}$ is finite as well;

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  assuming $a,b \ge 0$ the posted inequality is equivalent to the [root mean square inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality):

$$
\frac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}
$$

For $r \ge 1$ the natural extension would be the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Definition):

$$
\frac{a+b}{2} \le \left(\frac{a^r+b^r}{2}\right)^\cfrac{1}{r}
$$

Combining that with the triangle inequality for arbitrary reals gives:

$$
|a+b| \,\le\, |a|+|b| \,\le\, 2 \, \left(\frac{|a|^r+|b|^r}{2}\right)^\cfrac{1}{r} \;\;\iff\;\; |a+b|^r \,\le\, 2^{r-1}\left(|a|^r+|b|^r\right) \;\;\text{for}\;r \ge 1
$$

Comment: ...and this is tight as can be seen by taking $a=b=1$.

Comment: @Wojowu For any $\,a=b\,$ indeed.

Comment: That's beautiful... Thank you